# jcarousel continuous image slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

It's my first post here. I have this simple web site www.kanalistart.com and there you can see an image sliding around but not continuously. Here are the current settings if the script. What can I do to make it unstoppable. Thanks!

```js
// Default configuration properties.
    var defaults = {
        vertical: false,
        start: 1,
        offset: 1,
        size: null,
        scroll: 9,
        visible: null,
        animation: 'normal',
        easing: 'swing',
        auto: 0,
        wrap: null,
        initCallback: null,
        reloadCallback: null,
        itemLoadCallback: null,
        itemFirstInCallback: null,
        itemFirstOutCallback: null,
        itemLastInCallback: null,
        itemLastOutCallback: null,
        itemVisibleInCallback: null,
        itemVisibleOutCallback: null,
        buttonNextHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonPrevHTML: '<div></div>',
        buttonNextEvent: 'click',
        buttonPrevEvent: 'click',
        buttonNextCallback: null,
        buttonPrevCallback: null
    };
```

Comment: See `wrap` : http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/reference/configuration.html#wrap

Comment: Take a look at the Twitter Bootstrap carousel's javascript. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/carousel.js